# Does anybody know anything about astrology to figure out what 優先度 has to do with the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

https://cocoloni.jp/fortune/1362383/
英国占星術で占う「あの人の今、あなたに対する優先度」【無料占い】

I think its trying to ask, "How important is this persons whereabouts in regards to your priority" or
"His priority of you for now." or "Where does this person place you in regards to your priorities? Who on earth can correctly figure this out? I mean, this sentence can mean 1 of a thousand different things...

All I know is that the below definitely means:

『あの人の今！？』"Where are they now?"

Answer (score 1):

> あの人の今、あなたに対する優先度
> That person's current priority about/toward you

あの人の modifies 優先度 (i.e., "his priority" rather than "your priority"). ～に対する is usually translated like "about ～", "toward ～", "against ～", etc.

あの人の今 in isolation does mean "That person's current situation", where 今 is a noun. However, in the phrase in question, 今 is an adverb that modifies 対する, which is a verb. Don't be tricked by the comma after 今.

> Who on earth can correctly figure this out?

All native Japanese speakers can. I would say you can at least reject the interpretation of "your priority" only if you know how に対する works...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am very humbled by you assistance. I meant no harm by this post to any users, the stackexchange website as a whole, its affiliates or subsidiaries.